# Why my rpm installation hang while played remotely

Tags: bash, ssh, rpm, aix

I have an AIX 6.1 server where I want to uninstall a rpm.

This uninstallation can be done directly on the server :

```
[user@server]$ sudo /usr/bin/rpm -e --allmatches _MyRPM-1.0.0
```

This uninstallation is working.

I have a script lauching this unstallation :

**Uninstall.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -x

sudo /usr/bin/rpm -e --allmatches _MyRPM-1.0.0
```

I can play this script on the server without any problem :

```
[user@server]$ cd /where/is/the/script;./Uninstall.sh
+ sudo /usr/bin/rpm -e --allmatches _MyRPM-1.0.0
_MyRPM-1.0.0 has been uninstalled successfully
```

But when I'm playing this script remotely the rpm hang :

```
[user@client]$ ssh user@server "cd /where/is/the/script;./Uninstall.sh"
+ sudo /usr/bin/rpm -e --allmatches _MyRPM-1.0.0
```

And this command hang, I need to kill it in order to end the ssh.

**PS :** I have exactly the same comportment for installation or uninstallation.

**EDIT :**
The problem seems coming from the sudo. The hang problem appears also when I'm doing anithing with a sudo.

For example with a new script :
**test.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -x

sudo env
```

Comment: So you're not being prompted for password? Are you prompted when running ./uninstall.sh localy? Are you using the same userID on both machines? Do they share a common .ssh/key file? (Just guessing). Good luck.

Comment: I'm not being prompted for password, nor localy or remotely. The connexion is made by ssh public key.

Answer (score 0):

Sudo normally requires a user authenticate as themselves, and if I recall it can act different via remote execution due to the way the terminal is handled.

I don't have a system to test this on at the moment, but but you could try ssh's -t or -T switches:

```
 -T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation.

 -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.
         Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

I suspect you could get this to work by adding the script you're remotely executing into /etc/sudoers:

```
{user} ALL=NOPASSWD:/where/is/the/script/Uninstall.sh
```

Then try:

```
"ssh -t user@server /where/is/the/script/Uninstall.sh"
```

EDIT:

Found some details to help explain why sudo is behaving differently when executed remotely:

http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html

> The sudoers security policy requires that
>   most users authenticate themselves before they can use sudo. **A
>   password is not required if the invoking user is root, if the target
>   user is the same as the invoking user, or if the policy has disabled
>   authentication for the user or command.**

Perhaps it's hanging because it's trying to authenticate, whereas locally it wouldn't need to do so.

Comment: My problem is that I can't change the way the ssh is done, and the strange behaviour is the fact than a remote sudo executed directly (not in a script) is working : 'ssh user@server sudo env' works but 'ssh user@server test.sh' don't.

Comment: I've tried to duplicate, but I don't have access to an AIX box with any sudo rights. I can't get this to happen on Linux/SUSE. Wish I could help more!